# Using Drawflow library create nodes but they are not visible

Tags: javascript, css, django

I'm trying to use the amazing Drawflow library (Javascript) from:

https://github.com/jerosoler/Drawflow

Here is my code:

```html
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'drawflow/src/drawflow.css' %}">
</head>

<body>

    <div id="drawflow"></div>

    <script type='module'>
        // The minified version is build as an UMD module, so it cannot be imported
        // It should be rebuild eventually.
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75514648/uncaught-syntaxerror-the-requested-module-does-not-provide-an-export-named-dra
        import Drawflow from "{% static 'drawflow/src/drawflow.js' %}";
        import sheet from "{% static 'drawflow/src/drawflow.css' %}" assert { type: 'css'};
        import { h, getCurrentInstance, render } from 'https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.esm-browser.js'
        const Vue = { version: 3, h, render };

        const container = document.getElementById("drawflow");
        var editor = new Drawflow(container);

        editor.reroute = true;
        editor.editor_mode = 'edit';
        editor.start();
        editor.addModule('nameNewModule');
        
        const nodeData = {
          id: 'node-1',
          name: 'My Node',
          module: 'nameNewModule',
          x: 500,
          y: 100,
          class: '',
          html: function() {
            return '<div>' + this.name + '</div>';
          } ,
          inputs: {
            input_1: {
              label: 'Input 1',
            },
          },
          outputs: {
            output_1: {
              label: 'Output 1',
            },
          },
          data: {
            command: 'Run command',
          },
        };

        editor.addNode(nodeData.module, 
            Object.keys(nodeData.inputs).length,
            Object.keys(nodeData.outputs).length,
            nodeData.x, nodeData.y,
            nodeData.class, nodeData.data, nodeData.html());
    </script>

</body>
```

However, when I run this (using a Django server), I don't get any error, neither on the server nor in the console, and I checked the library is loaded, but I don't see anything.

However, I know the  elements are properly created as we can see here:

[image: drawflow div is visible]

If I turn off the property "position: absolute" on the element, I get something like this:

[image: Node is visible but has wrong geometry]

Now the node is visible but I can't do much with it and it has the wrong geometry. I can't drag it or do anything, and it's way too large and in the wrong position.

I don't really understand what is going on. When going on the live demo linked in the GitHub repo, it works, so I don't think it's a browser issue (I tried with Chrome, Opera, and Firefox).

I even try to get the source code of the live demo from the GitHub repo, and it didn't really work:

[image: Code from the live demo in the github repo]

If anyone can help, or see if they can reproduce this with the same code, thanks.

**Edit**: After further investigation, I kind of made it worked by turning off the properties "display: flex" and "overflow: hidden" in the parent-drawflow class. But I don't understand why I have to do this, and could I make it work without having to turn this off. Why does it work well in the live demo and not with me?

**Edit 2**: I manage to make this work by adding a `<div class='wrapper'>` around the `<div id='drawflow'>` and using the beautiful.css stylesheet from the live demo example. It seems the wrapper set the size, which wasn't done in the drawflow class.